# Single-threaded java program loads multiple cores

Tags: java, cpu-usage

We have a computationally demanding java program (scientific research) that is designed single-threaded. However, when executed, it loads much more than 1 CPU core (we noticed it the hard way - cluster job scheduler killed our program because it loaded more cores than requested). We encountered this weird phenomenon both on linux (Debian, Ubuntu) and windows (7).

I understand that there are several background threads added by java/jvm (garbage collector) so even single-threaded program can load more than one core but I doubt that these background processes could load another full core or two.

I ask for any idea what may be causing this. Thanks for any hints. Feel free to ask for any details, though I can't post the code here (first, it's quite a lot of code, second, it is still under research and I cannot publish anything yet).

Comment: It's silly to ask you post **all** the code. But it will help if you get piece of code which runs computations. Also it would be useful to see with what JVM arguments are you run the program.

Comment: What about memory issues? When you perform a lot of operation on memory and at some point you run out of memory then garbage collector might kick in and use cpu heavily.

Comment: Note that both OS and JVM could opt number of cores to process due to optimization. What about recursion and/or GPU? HDD reading?

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Let me first give you my condolences for having to run your program in an environment where someone has found it more intellectually fulfilling to kill jobs attempting to use more than one core, than to restrict jobs to using just one core. But let's move on with the question.</sup>

When I pause a random single-threaded java program and look at my debugger's thread listing there is about half a dozen threads in there.  That's just how the JVM works.  There is at least one thread for the garbage collection, another thread for running finalizers, and various other stuff, most of which I don't even know what purpose they serve.  We lost the game of knowing precisely what is going on in our machines a couple of decades ago.

There may be options that you could use to tell the JVM to reduce its use of threads, for example to run garbage-collection in the same thread as your program, but I don't know them by heart, so you would need to look them up, and frankly, I doubt that it would make much difference.  There will always be threads that you have no control over.

So, it seems like you are going to have to configure your own job to not use more than one core.  I have done it at work, with some success, but today is Saturday, so I do not have access to the script files that I used, so I am going to try and help with whatever I remember.

The concepts you are looking for are "process thread affinity" and "NUMA".

Under Windows, the `start` command (built into cmd.exe) allows you to specify the number of logical CPUs (in other words, cores) to run your process on.  `start /affinity 1 myapp` will run `myapp` limiting it on core 1.

Under Linux there are at least a couple of different commands that allow you to launch a process on a limited subset of cores.  One that I know of is `taskset` and another is `numactl`.

Comment: Not to mention that (at least on Windows) the task scheduler might reschedule a single thread on different cores, after IO or other types of waits.

Answer (score 1):

There are [set of parameters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) for JVM you could play. For Java 7 and earlier:

- **-XX:ParallelGCThreads=n** Sets the number of threads used during parallel phases of the garbage collectors.
- **-XX:ConcGCThreads=n** Number of threads concurrent garbage collectors will use

For Java 8 there are another options which depends on OS. You could see them for Windows [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html). Some you could find helpful:

- **-XX:CICompilerCount=threads** Sets the number of compiler threads to use for compilation
- **-XX:ConcGCThreads=threads** Sets the number of threads used for concurrent GC. *The default value depends on the number of CPUs available to the JVM (!possible cause of your problem!)*
- **-XX:ParallelGCThreads=threads** Sets the number of threads used for parallel garbage collection in the young and old generations. *The default value depends on the number of CPUs available to the JVM*
- **-XX:+UseParNewGC** Enables the use of parallel threads for collection in the young generation. By default, this option is disabled (*but it could be enabled due to another options*)

---

If you provide us additional info then answers would be more helpful and informative